# Load HTML before external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I want my HTML to be fully loaded before the external javascript file executes.
When I load my index.html the javascript executes and I get an alert box popped up before I see my HTML content. How do I load the HTML content first and then get the pop up window?

```js
    var todos = ["Eat dinner"];
    var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
    
    while(input !== "quit") {
        if(input === "list") {
            console.log(todos);
        }
        else if(input === "new") {
            // ask for a new ToDo
            var newTodo = prompt("Enter a new ToDo item");
            // add to ToDo's array
            todos.push(newTodo);
        }
        input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
    }
    console.log("Ok, you quit the app! :/");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sv-se">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>1.0 Javascript-kod</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>"new" - Add a new ToDo item</li>
            <li>"list" - View all my ToDo items</li>
            <li>"quit" - Quit App</li>
        </ul>

        <!-- <script src="assets/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
        <script src="assets/js/todo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is running after you HTML is loaded, your problem is your then blocking the main executing thread with your alerts.  But running this snippet I actually do see the HTML first.  But what you could maybe do is place your script inside a `setTimeout` to give UI a chance to render on browsers where it doesn't.

Comment: You have to create a button and trigger a function on it and pull all your javaScript code into it or you can use time delay function in javascript or jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the explicit answers. I now understand what happens and will create a button with an eventListener.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
(function()(
    alert("DOM loaded succesfully");
    var todos = ["Eat dinner"];
    var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

    while(input !== "quit") {
    if(input === "list") {
        console.log(todos);
    }
    else if(input === "new") {
        // ask for a new ToDo
        var newTodo = prompt("Enter a new ToDo item");
        // add to ToDo's array
        todos.push(newTodo);
    }
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
  }
  console.log("Ok, you quit the app! :/");
))();
```

Its pure javascript thing that checks DOM is loaded succesfully `(function(){})();`.

Comment: `(function(){})();`  That's just an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, how is that waiting for the DOM, were did you get this info?.

Comment: It is self executing method i think. It works like a `$(document).ready(function(){ });`. And i use this `(function(){ })();` when i am using pure js.

Comment: `$(document).ready` is different, it's a shorthand for the DOM ready.   But `(function(){ })();` is not the same thing, it will not release the thread and wait for DOM ready, you will find this is identical to doing.. `function run() {}` and then calling `run()`.  ``(function(){ })();`` is often used to create a closure..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you can put your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //HERE SHOULD BE YOUR CODE
});
```

Comment: I do not want to use jQuery. Gotta be a way to do this in plain JavaScript, right?

Comment: `Gotta be a way to do this in plain JavaScript, right?`  Seen as jQuery is written in Javascript, yes.. :)   You could maybe look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code in an event handler and not at the parse time:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    /* your code goes here */
});
```

But remember it may wait for images etc. to load too. If you need to execute something when the DOM tree is fully loaded, but everything else is not yet, stick to placing your script just before `</body>`. Although DOM parsing technically has still not finished, it won't add anything to the tree at that moment nevertheless.